# MERGE SQL Stagement - Identity Table

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2012

How do I preserver SK on table using Merge into statement?

I got this situation bellow  :

[image]

But, the row represents Ferrari , got updated to Porshe, but when trying to use MERGE INTO on IDENTITY table, loads increment SK on  column , however I would like  to preserve , because represents the same guy who own theses car's.

Output bellow when I'm using MERGE INTO

[image]

I would like that output :

[image]

How do i solve this problem ?

That's script bellow :

```
MERGE INTO Test1 AS target
USING
    (SELECT [name], Sex, Car
     FROM
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT [name], Sex, Car           
        FROM Stage AS Src
        ) A
    ) AS source ([name], Sex, Car)
ON target.[ID] = source.[ID]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT([name], Sex, Car)
    VALUES([name], Sex, Car)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET
        target.[name] = source.[name]
        , target.Sex = source.Sex
        , target.Car = source.Car;
```

THERES ID REFFERS TO NAME ALEXANDRE , REPRESENTED BY '1'

Comment: I don't get it: how do you **uniquely** identify rows to match up for the merge?

Comment: Are you saying `sk` is an `IDENTITY` column? How can that be if `2` already occurs twice? I suggest you create a primary key for that table, and use that in the `merge` and set `sk` to what you want it to be

Comment: @CharLieFace theres ID on table, that situation above its example when im using on production enviroment. But i got Id that reffers the name !

Comment: The `merge` needs to join on a unique column or columns, or you will get incorrect results